# Stack Overflow sites usability with JavaScript disabled

Tags: discussion, user-experience

For security reasons I moved from considering disabling JavaScript to actually doing that. Stack Overflow site collection is one of the many that range from not barely practical to unusable without JavaScript. Being forced to boldly trust itches. I don't.

Second, web usability standards recommend, as common sense does, web sites should degrade gracefully if JavaScript (or CSS, wink to text browsers) is disabled. I haven't checked all the disabilities but I at least can no longer vote without JavaScript. There might be other unpleasant spots.

JavaScript **must** be an option, not a requirement.

So is there a plan to make Stack Overflow work gracefully without Java Script?

Or is there at least a reason why it has been made mandatory?

Not being able to vote (for instance) is not exactly an issue for me but I'm curious.

Shall it be taken as a sanction for disabling a backdoor to my system? (Just playing the Devil's Advocate.)

Comment: `is there at least a reason why it has been made mandatory?` a simple one - they don't want to waste an immense amount of money for extremely little gain. Making a web site degrade gracefully is *extremely* work intensive and adds loads of new complexities and considerations to both front-end and back-end design and  development. In this day and age, a couple of people disabling Javascript is not enough to justify the weeks or months in expensive developer time. Supporting the blind or disabled is a worthwhile thing to put extra effort in. Supporting folks who turn off JS, not so much.

Comment: Complaining about sites not working without JS is so last decade.

Comment: Interacting with the world wide web nowadays requires javascript. This has been the case for probably the last five years at least. I also used to block all javascript on sites, but we've long moved past the point where that is practical. Engineering solutions for the tiny minority that will have it disabled is probably not a worthwhile task for a public website.

Comment: Graceful degradation is only hard if you don't care about it, or if you're some kind of service that can't possibly degrade gracefully. Stack Overflow can and should degrade gracefully. Not degrading gracefully when it is possible to do so is like using "Image description here" as the alt text for an image.

Comment: _"For security reasons I moved from considering disabling JavaScript to actually doing that."_ What security reason do you have for not trusting JS to run on SO?

Comment: Exactly. Turning it off for weird unknown sites I get. But for a major site powered by a million-dollar company? Why?

Comment: @Cerbrus I find your question highly astonishing and revealing. I don't just boldly trust strangers, especially people I never have and probably will never learn to know in person. Trust is earned, not to be considered granted by default.

Comment: So, you have no reason for disabling JS on SO, other than (to be blunt), paranoia. Got it.

Comment: I see the mindset. So @Pekka웃 the richer the more trustworthy, right? I get that.

Comment: `the richer the more trustworthy, right?` To an extent, yes - the more a company has to lose by acting unethically or criminally, or negligently the more likely it is to be extra careful to not act unethically or criminally or negligently. But it's clear this is not going to be a reasonable discussion.  If you don't trust SO not to break into your computer, simply don't use SO. End of.

Comment: I don't get it anyway. The most distrustful aspect of the web is other users on the web, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Your logic is flawed. I hereby don't trust SO for the over-trust SO has in itself to believe itself unbreakable. That's the kind of reasonning that's worrisome. Too big to fail has been uncountably proven wrong and that's you're telling me to believe in. Sorry, I don't... buy that.

Comment: Nonsense. For JS on SO to pose a security threat, two things would have to happen *at the same time:* 1. Stack Overflow would have to turn evil, or have its servers compromised. 2. An unpatched exploit would have to exist for your browser and/or operating system. It is not reasonable to be worried about this. Life is full of much greater risks. You're probably more likely to get hurt in a car accident.

Comment: In the 3 odd years you've been using SO with javascript enabled - has anything happened to make you go "nope - turning that off now for SO - don't trust that one anymore and I want it to work without JS..." except a general distrust for JS?

Comment: *"Javascript must be an option, not a requirement."* That's your strongly worded opinion, but it has no bearing on reality. There is nothing that JavaScript "must" be, and on Stack Overflow (and the vast majority of the rest of the Internet) it *is* a requirement, not an option. If you want to use a site on the Internet (or *any* piece of software) then you accept that site's requirements or you're on your own.

Comment: Everyone is attacking the OPs reason for disabling JavaScript, but that doesn't mean that an understandable reason does not exist. It should actually be fairly simple to make all of the core functionality work without the use of JavaScript, while still keeping the functionality the same for the average user. This isn't rocket surgery.

Comment: This would also solve the problem of users in China being unable to use the site, though that's also an unpopular proposal.

Comment: @TinyGiant You *massively* underestimate the effort involved in doing so. Maintaining what is fundamentally two web apps in one codebase is anything but trivial.

Comment: I see the OP has deleted their account now...

Comment: @DavyM why would anyone keep an account on a site that has such a negative view on basic accessibility principles? Everyone would rather invent complexity out of thin air and lie to themselves than think critically about the problem. It is no surprise that the OP deleted their account. What has transpired here is absolutely disgusting.

Comment: @TinyGiant  Nobody has a "negative view of accessibility", nobody is lying to themselves, nobody is inventing complexity and calling what has transpired here "absolutely disgusting" is *incredibly* hyperbolic. You're free to disagree, but you're not *debating* this in anything resembling a constructive way. You could start by assuming good intentions from the people you're talking to, rather than accusing us all of lying to ourselves and being unwilling to think critically. Most of the people disagreeing have as much or more experience than you.

Comment: @meagar I agree he's being hyperbolic, and I don't agree with (some) of the sentiments expressed in the original question, but the overall response to this question did strike me as fairly dismissive. The asker expressed legitimate security concerns related to a system (website + browser + JS), but seems to lack an understanding of why things are prioritized the way they are by those who implement things. Responses largely seem to focus instead on the fact that SE itself is trustworthy, and some even go so far as to claim JS isn't a legitimate security concern (which is nonesense!).

Comment: @user69513 JS isn't a security concern. JS in combination with holes in the browser sandbox may be; but that's still a problem of holes in the sandbox. It is not specific to JavaScript, any security issue in the browser could be exploited and has been exploited.

Answer (score 15):

In my opinions, nowadays, there is no good reason to disable JS in browsers completely.

Sure, for sketchy websites you may not even want to visit in the first place, I get it, but for *reputable* websites like Stack Overflow, I've yet to see a ***proper, verifiable security concern*** in running JavaScript.

There are plenty of browser plugins that allow you to white-list certain sites, while blocking JS on others. I'd suggest using one of those.

That is, if you trust the plugin not to hack into your system...

Or your browser, for that matter. What has your browser done to earn your trust?
Heck, even the OS can have security issues. Better block that as well.

---

Silliness aside, it's unreasonable to expect *full* functionality without JavaScript, nowadays.

You chose to disable a core function of browsing the web. The consequences of that choice are your own "problem", not that of every single website you visit.

Basically: You disable something > you get a reduced experience.

Comment: Actually ad networks are often used to spread malware, even on reputable sites. Luckily the SE network is immune to this given how they do things.

Comment: Is Spectre a proper, verifiable security concern to you?

Comment: +1 to Stack Overflow for hosting their own vetted ads, @user69513 ;-)

Comment: @Nasha: __Spectre was never an issue__ on Stack Overflow in the first place. Don't buy into the __hysteria / paranoia__.

Comment: @Nasha What? No! Spectre isn't an issue (well not since the patches I hope), but [other sorts of malware](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/02/ad-network-uses-advanced-malware-technique-to-conceal-cpu-draining-mining-ads) are.

Comment: @user69513: Let's not bring irrelevant "issues" into this.

Comment: Well if one is going to raise objections, they should at least be well-founded. But I agree, it doesn't apply to SO (thankfully).

Answer (score 3):

Okay fine, disable JavaScript. But have you tried jQuery?

Look, its use is not required. Where did you read that? Maybe in 1999 that was a thing.

I am pretty sure that by usability you are referring to accessibility, which is a thing, sure. It is important, but it also has nothing to do with JavaScript being enabled.

> they represent an opinion that requiring Javascript for a web application is an automatic accessibility violation. This might be partly a historical feeling, as some older accessibility standards contained language that said (or could be taken to imply) that in order to be accessible, a site had to work with Javascript turned off. I don’t know what motivated the inclusion of those clauses at the time, but would note that most modern accessibility standards merely say that one’s site must be accessible (regardless of whether or not it uses or requires client-side scripting). -[WebAIM: Javascript as an accessibility concern](https://webaim.org/blog/javascript-as-an-accessibility-concern/)

That said, there are certainly strong suggestions for web sites to be usable while JavaScript is disabled. Not being able to use features while JavaScript is disabled is certainly an issue you can raise, preferably a question citing a specific broken usage with <strike>screen shots</strike> hand drawn red circles and a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag so that it can be looked at, perhaps, in 6-8 <strike>weeks</strike> years.

Overall, the situation you are describing only effects a very small percentage of users internet-wide, and more than likely (since this site is devoted to users who do write code) an even smaller percentage of Stack Overflow users. While it may be inconvenient from certain tin hat perspectives, it is essentially required in modern internet browsing usage to have JavaScript enabled. I̭̖̖̞̱̬f̵̥ y̭͎͈̤o̻̩͉ų͖͈̭̺ͅ ̴͚͉a͎̖͓r̷̰̯̺̙e̻̱̦͔̜͚͍ ̩͚̀u̳̘̹͉̲ͅͅn͉̳̤̜h̹̮a̟͈p̰͓̝̟͈͉̼p͓͖̰ͅy̧ ̷͖w̠̫̰͎̹i͏̘̞͙̖̘̝t̢̼̬͎h̙ ̮̲̣͘ț̘̦͠h̛a̶̜̲̼t̮̱̪̹,̟̠̻͍ ̣̫̟͖͞t͚͔̬̮͟h͈̻e̝̙͚̬̦͔̞͟n̤̱͍ ̘̝̕p̙̹̟ͅe̸͔̻̲̱̥̦̳r̹̕h͎̗̥̖̜͕̹a̸p̨̯̣͖s̯ ͚̭̤͚̲ͅí̝ͅt ̬̦̤͍̬̠i̻̕s̠̀ ͏t͏͚̠̝̮i̡m̞̤̜͇̪e̪̰͍̠ t͕̦ơ ͔̯͎̰̥͟m̘̭̲̪͚o̧̦̠̫̱̟̙v̳͍̬e ̵̪̲̮̺oņ͙̥̫͍̮ ̱̤͍͙̰̲͝t̩o͓͈ ̗̤̺u̧̥̣̭͚͍s̵̺̫ͅͅi̫ǹ͕̙̭̦g̞̤͔̜̩ ͚̞a̝͔̣͜ ͇͙̬͈te͇͕͚͙̲ͅc͟ͅh͕̪̭ͅn̩o̭̫͇̫͡l͕̝̬̙o̺̰̘̗g̥͓y̮̕ ̗̺̗̗̣o͜t҉̝̝̙͇̪̳h̷̗͈ͅe̱͍͜r̯̪̫̤̝ ̵̯̭̮̩th̝̘̬͈̬̱͞a͏̟̞ͅn͚ ͏̣͕̗̖a͉̥n͕̤̘̥̭͠ͅ ̬͍͕i͈̗̰̘͉̖͡ṋt̠̻̰e͏͔̘̜͍r̺̖͎̀n̹̘̕ḙ̸t̯́ ̷̦̟̺͙ͅb͟r̦͎͚͉̪͓̼o̭̟w͚͉͚͎ś͙̱é̙r̭̟͓̘̙͙.̙̜̦̫͕̙͝

Comment: It's time for [Gopher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol))  to make a come back :p

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd like to be clear. None of the concerns about JavaScript apply to the StackExchange network as far as I'm aware, and at present it seems reasonable to me to trust them enough to run the JavaScript they provide - in my completely run-of-the-mill, security hardened, regularly updated, tab-sandboxing, battle tested browser (it's just Firefox). It seems to me that worrying about running JavaScript on any major, reasonably trustworthy site is a bit silly at this point. There are certainly some privacy consequences to choosing to do so, but at present that's the price you pay for full functionality.

To be honest, as far as the web as a whole (not SE) goes, I do agree with you in principle. I too run NoScript. On the privacy front, we have (*at minimum*) **serious privacy concerns** due to [fingerprinting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122385) and [analytics](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2017/11/websites_use_se.html). On the security front there's JavaScript malware showing up in [banner ads](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/12/millions-exposed-to-malvertising-that-hid-attack-code-in-banner-pixels/), in [your inbox](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/04/26/ransomware-in-your-inbox-the-rise-of-malicious-javascript-attachments/), and even [ads that mine crypto](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/02/ad-network-uses-advanced-malware-technique-to-conceal-cpu-draining-mining-ads/). As if the security concerns weren't enough, the resource usage and terrible load times of bloated sites definitely is. However, as others have noted many features are simply not feasible without JavaScript (at least for a reasonable cost). For better or worse, we seem to be stuck with (an awful lot of) it.

Ultimately, in the name of pragmatism I would encourage you to consider white listing non-3rd party scripts (and a few 3rd party ones as well, such as MathJax and various frameworks) for those sites you do trust, such as the SE network. For untrusted sites visited infrequently, using the `temporarily allow` option is sadly going to be a necessity for the foreseeable future.

As an aside, before you even begin to worry about JavaScript have you gotten on top of [WebRTC](https://mozillamediagoddess.org/2015/09/10/webrtc-privacy)? What about your [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer), and all the other things that can be used to [fingerprint](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) you? To be blunt, your browser is a leaky boat as far as your privacy is concerned. Unless you're browsing some pretty questionable websites, JavaScript is probably not of too much concern outside of the excessive resource usage by some.

Comment: _" resource usage and terrible load times of bloated sites definitely is"_ That's really a `199x` argument... The problem is that the OP doesn't trust SO in the first place.

Comment: @cerbrus Again you have not gotten my point. But I agree it's now the demonstrated excess of self confidence that makes me doubt. It wasn't *at the time I posted my question*.

Comment: @Nasha: You've failed to make your point. You haven't provided a _real_ security concern.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think he's objecting to JS in principle and is frustrated when doing without proves not feasible. I empathize, but the reality is that it's a widely used tool now. I'd honestly prefer it wasn't, but oh well.

Comment: To be fair, that _is_ your point, albeit diluted. "I don't trust SO" rather than "I don't trust anyone", but the effect and response is identical. You've asked in the context of SO, answers you get are also going to be in the context of SO.

Comment: @user69513: Come on, this while "No JS!" movement is so outdated. There's also no good alternative. You're going to have _some_ code in your website.

Comment: In that respect yes @Cerbrus, but don't forget there's still Disability legislation to account for. Requiring JS usually implies non compliance. If OP was approaching from that angle (with a specific gripe) I'd have more sympathy

Comment: @Cerbrus I acknowledge that it isn't reasonable to expect it to go away at this point, but I don't think such a "movement" is "outdated" to the extent that the concerns surrounding JavaScript are very real and haven't gone away. It causes a huge number of problems that are very frustrating, but is also an extremely powerful tool that makes many otherwise impossible things possible. What I'm getting at is that I don't mind MathJax, but I'd rather some newspaper website didn't run JS if I could help it. Could Walmart.com *be* any more bloated?

Comment: @user69513: Are you talking about _security_ or about _privacy_ problems?

Comment: @Cerbrus Both! Although as time goes on, it seems to be increasingly privacy and usability, and decreasingly security (thankfully).

Comment: @Clive: Aren't screen readers capable of triggering JS events? Shouldn't these tools ___evolve___ along with the web, instead of holding it back?

Comment: @user69513 And we can't blame SO for these privacy issues on other sites. Again: Sure, block JS, but expect reduced functionality if you do.

Comment: @Cerbrus To the screen reader comment: JS can get... pretty arbitrary and stuff, being Turing complete and all that. Not an easy problem to tackle for tools for those who are impaired when loading and displaying the website is more like running an entire (continuous) program. To the SO comment, yes I agree, I understand why SE elects to use it and choose to trust them.

Comment: @Cerbrus In many cases yes, I believe so, and yes they should and do. But there are plenty of edge cases in JS where a screen reader just can't convey the same intent that the manipulation made by JS did to a person not using one. I'm not getting on a soapbox here, just a passing somewhat-related comment